# how to create multiple bullets with the forEach function

Tags: javascript

```
var data = {
    pets:[
        {
            type: "Dogs Breeds",
            name: "Dog",
            breed: ["Dalmation", "Poodle", "Shitzu"]
        },
        {
            type: "Cats Breeds",
            name:"Cat",
            breed:["Ragdoll", "Scottish Fold", "Sphynx"]
        },
        {
            type: "Rabbits Breeds",
            name: "Rabbit",
            breed: ["Holland Lop", "Rex", "Mini Lop"]
        }
    ]

};

var content = document.getElementById("content")


data.pets.forEach(pets => {
    let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    let h1text = document.createTextNode(pets.name);
    h1.appendChild(h1text);
    content.appendChild(h1);

    let h2 = document.createElement("h2");
    let h2text = document.createTextNode(pets.type);
    h2.appendChild(h2text);
    content.appendChild(h2);

    let ul = document.createElement("ul")
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    let text = document.createTextNode(pets.breed);
    li.appendChild(text);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    content.appendChild(ul);
})
```

This is my code and I need to results to come up as separate bullet points for the breed category. I'm pretty sure the the issue stems from the fact that the ul is in the forEach so each iteration only sees the breed line as one name. I'm not sure how to fix this please help!!

Comment: Create the `<ul>` outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

Is this the result you are looking for?

**Nested Loop**

You can do a nested looping (a `.forEach()` in another  `.forEach()`) to loop through `pets` and loop through the `breed` in `pets`

```js
var data = {
    pets:[
        {
            type: "Dogs Breeds",
            name: "Dog",
            breed: ["Dalmation", "Poodle", "Shitzu"]
        },
        {
            type: "Cats Breeds",
            name:"Cat",
            breed:["Ragdoll", "Scottish Fold", "Sphynx"]
        },
        {
            type: "Rabbits Breeds",
            name: "Rabbit",
            breed: ["Holland Lop", "Rex", "Mini Lop"]
        }
    ]

};

var content = document.getElementById("content")


data.pets.forEach(pets => {
    let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    let h1text = document.createTextNode(pets.name);
    h1.appendChild(h1text);
    content.appendChild(h1);

    let h2 = document.createElement("h2");
    let h2text = document.createTextNode(pets.type);
    h2.appendChild(h2text);
    content.appendChild(h2);

    let ul = document.createElement("ul")
    pets.breed.forEach(val=>{
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      let text = document.createTextNode(val);
      li.appendChild(text);
      ul.appendChild(li);
    })
    content.appendChild(ul);
})
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```